# How to convert LaTeX to mathml code directly?

Tags: mathml

In microsoft word it can't understand every mathematical equation that I input in latex correctly.the only language that it understands correctly is the mathml code. But to do so I have to input the equation in latex to this script in a notepad [example]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
Your test: $$\mathbf{F}_{2}=k \frac{q_{1} q_{2} \hat{\mathbf{r}}_{21}}{r_{21}^{2}}$$
</body>
</html>
```

then I have to save this file as a HTML file.Then I have to open the file in chrome and when the equation appears I have to extract the mathml code[by right clicking the equation and selecting to show the code].Then when I paste the code in word as keep text only,then it gives the exact equation.
Is there any easier way like a software or an online converter to convert latex into Mathml code[not mathml]?
thank you

Comment: I've added an answer to that post using this example.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail how to install latexml in windows?

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/get.html

Comment: If the answers to the existing questions don't help you, perhaps set a bounty to that question to attract readers and writers. If your question is different, perhaps make that clear by editing it or by posting a new specific question.